# use the same 'www' and 'plugin' folders in ionic for 2 differents app

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

What is the best way to achieve it?
I have one app built with ionic and I want to create a new one, which will have the same code, but it should be differnt app(id, name, icon, splash).

thanks

Comment: in config.xml change the package name than it will create 2 apps

Answer (score 0):

Ok you need to edit the name in ionic.project and also config.xml and run the following

```
ionic platform remove [android or ios]
```

and then

```
ionic platform add [android or ios]
```

Comment: each time I want to publish one of the app in need to remove and add again the platform?

Comment: yes and have you followed my answer and it works for you?